# Get Geotiffs Index from NASA data

Tags: r, geospatial, raster

[NASA has their 500m resolution lights at night data](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/NightLights/page3.php) in inexplicable projection and format on where they cut the boundaries (or am I missing something?).

I'd like to have a function like this (made up, not work):

```
###Made up, not work
getTILE("Australia")
[1] D2

getTILE("United States")
[1] A1 B1
```

This is so that a separate function that needs to download the GeoTiffs by country can do so without downloading the whole set. These tiles are huge ~225mb each, so downloading the whole set in the function is really slowing it down.

Seems like whacky formatting on NASA's part here… just sayin. They could have just chopped this in sinusoidal MODIS tiles and I wouldn't have this problem…

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!